# Hash Shard Map with SQL Azure

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-scale

I've been doing some [reading](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management/) about sharding SQL Azure databases with Azure Elastic Scale. The [article](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management/) discusses two types of shard maps: **List** and **Range**. What about **Hash** shard maps? My application requirements are to evenly distribute data across shards which would seem to require a hashing of the shard key. Is this possible with SQL Azure and Azure Elastic Scale?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point in time Elastic Database tools (formerly known as Elastic Scale) doesn't support hash shard maps.

Thanks

Silvia Doomra

Comment: You can make a 'do-it-yourself' hash shard map by hashing your shard key yourself and then using a RangeShardMap on the hash values. If you ever plan to do data movement with Split-Merge you will need to store the hash value in the sharded tables so that Split-Merge knows which rows to move.

Comment: One way to "store" the hash values in the database is to add a computed column where the computation implements the same hash function that you are also using in your code.